# How to mock ES6 module's function in same file?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'm using Jest and I've encountered the following problem:

I've got a method named `getStyle` inside `helpers.js` file. Method internally calls another method, named `getTransition` and returns an object.

To test the method properly I have to assert that the returned object matches my testing criteria and that `getTransition` is called properly.

How do I mock `getTransition` as in `jest.fn()` to check for `mock.calls` ?

```
let myMock = jest.fn();
jest.mock("../src/helpers.js", () => {
    getTransition: myMock
});

it("gets style", () => {
    let style = getStyle(object, 100);

    expect(style.height).toBe("100px");
    expect(style.transition).not.toBeUndefined();
    expect(style.transition).not.toBeNull();
    expect(myMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
});
```

But mymock.mock.calls is empty. How do I mock the method in the same module from where I'm importing the method I need to be tested?

Comment: _To test the method properly_ - do not mock `getTransition` method. `getTransition` method is implementation details which you shouldn't care about, unless `getTransition` method calls some webservice or other external resources, which makes tests slow

Comment: I don't need it mocked to return data or so, I'm ok with the data retrieved by the original `getTransition` method. I just need to assert it's been called properly, by asserting the arguments received and the number of calls.

Comment: You need to test that `style.transition` is expected value. You don't need to care about how `getTransition` called as long as `getStyle` behave as expected.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know that. I thought if for example I have if-else in my method, I need to test both scenarios for if/else with mocking functions in if/else and checking for calls. But as you said, i guess this is implementation detail and I don't need it mocked. Thank you for your help !